# Android - Migrating Recurring Job From Job Dispatcher to Work Manager - Do I need to cancel the old job?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, firebase-job-dispatcher

So I am working on removing all background tasks started via `JobDispatcher` and replacing them with `WorkManager`. I have most of the work done, but I am curious on how to cancel a job that was set to be recurring with lifetime set to `FOREVER`.

When refactoring, I removed all references to the old job scheduled by `JobDispatcher`, but I was noticing an error saying `Unable to bind to MyJobService` when testing the upgrade path from the version that used `JobDispatcher` and my new `WorkManager` version. I am guessing that the old job is just running forever, is this the case? Does the job automatically cancel or will I need to manually stop the job before starting the new background worker using `WorkManager`?

Comment: It will be lost on a device reboot. I would not worry about it.

Comment: @YavorMitev Are there docs/examples of this somewhere? The documentation when setting `Lifetime.FOREVER` states that the job will persist, even across device reboots.